# Spring Mongo Repository is unable to match String to ObjectId in _id field

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a data class with a String Id and I'm saving it into the mongoDB with a null value to get an autogenerated replacement.

```
@Document(collection="applications")
@TypeAlias(Constants.Application)
public class DataApplication implements IApplication{

@Id
@Field("id")
private String id = null;

...
}
```

This works as expected however I'm facing a problem in that I cannot seem to findById from the Spring Mongo Repo. It is capable of persisting and retrieving without problems, creating BSON like

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5ef9a579bafa09b36225e743c"),
   Other fields and things
}
```

However, this seems to be specifically about when attempting to find using the id field.
Its very weird that it isn't using the Id field name I specified, however as when I retrieve multiple objects at once they convert back into POJOs as expected I do not believe this is an issue.

From what I can see this seems to be a result of the MongoDB storing the values as ObjectId's, as I am able to retrieve by Id when I persist an object with a String Id value, when I pull the Applications into Java to compare, or when I create Examples that match all fields except Id, however Examples fails when I set an Id to compare against.

[Prevent Spring Data for Mongo to convert ids to ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329175/prevent-spring-data-for-mongo-to-convert-ids-to-objectid) seems to be related as it mentions the underlying query structure, unfortunately I seem to have the opposite problem.

Comment: I can retreive them by fetching all, fetching paged or just fetching by example and matching non Id Fields.
The value appears to just be the ObjectId as a string.

Comment: Sure has that helped?

Answer (score 2):

`@Field` annotation is used to define custom metadata for document fields. For example:

```
@Field(targetType = DECIMAL128)
private BigDecimal value;

@Field("fName")
private String firstName;
```

When you defined `@Field("id") private String id = null;` it is interpreted as the field `id` as another field `id` not the document identifier field `_id`. Because, the annotation's `name` attribute is specified as "id". You can verify this as well in the following example using the `Person` Pojo class:

```
public class Person {
    
    @Field("id")
    private String id = null;

    private String name;
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // other get / set methods ...

    public String toString() {
       return "id: " + id + ", " + name;
    }
}
```

Using `MongoRepository` methods insert and query documents in `person` collection:

```
Person p1 = new Person("J.Doe");
//p1.setId("000");
repo.insert(p1);

List<Person> list = repo.findAll();
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will insert a document (as queried from the `mongo` shell) and print the `toString` representation as:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef5c92b70babc5a961350e5"), "name" : "J.Doe", "_class" : "com.example.demo.Person" }
```

Prints as: `id: null, J.Doe`

If you un-comment the code `p1.setId("000");` and run it again, you will find the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef5cab8306d071b13d3c16e"), "id" : "000", "name" : "J.Doe", "_class" : "com.example.demo.Person" }
```

And, prints as: `id: 000, J.Doe`

The code is behaving alright. Note the two fields, the `_id` and `id`. The `@Field` is to be used for customizing a document field.

To properly indicate the `id` field is to be used for `_id` document key field you can use the following. When the document is created the `_id` value will be the driver generated `ObjectId`:

- Annotate the `id` field as `@Id`, `@MongoId` or the `@Field` (without the
  `name`attribute).
- Not annotate at all.

**Note on Annotations:**

- [@Id](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/Id.html):
  Applied at the field level to mark the field used for identity
  purpose.
- [@MongoId](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/2.2.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/MongoId.html):
  Applied at the field level to mark the field used for identity
  purpose. Accepts an optional FieldType to customize id conversion.
- @Field: Applied at the field level it allows to describe the name and
  type of the field as it will be represented in the MongoDB BSON
  document thus allowing the name and type to be different than the
  field name of the class as well as the property type.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not whats happening. Weirdly it just seems to be treating the id field as _id in the database. At least as far as the BSON goes it seems to match the id into _id and back, even though I think it should be behaving as you describe.
So I would see
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef5b9bd5aa2275b7b0d131b") } if I didn't set it or { "_id" : "000" } if I did.

Comment: How do you know that id field is treated as _id? You can change the @Field("id") to @Field("id2") and see what happens.

Comment: There is some typing error in my post - I will correct it in couple of minutes.

Comment: I've corrected my answer to explain what is happening. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also see this post about that when a reference field is not set (i.e., a `null` value) in the Pojo object, the application doesn't create the field in the inserted document: [Spring Data MongoRepository Saving Objects with Differing Numbers of Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442142/spring-data-mongorepository-saving-objects-with-differing-numbers-of-fields/62443511#62443511).

Comment: Okay, using MongoId worked after I set the FieldType to ObjectId as implicit didn't seem to be enough.
I think the reason that the id was being saved as _id rather than the field name was since there was no data in it the BSON didn't record the field and it created a default value.