# ObjectId type formatting for MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In java Spring and under MongoDB i declare a field ObjectId (the `Id` of the class) (org.bson.types.ObjectId) and i get the field in this format :

```
"id": {
        "timestamp": 125945532265,
        "machineIdentifier": 1252265214,
        "processIdentifier": 127288,
        "counter": 936021898,
        "date": "2020-07-12T11:27:45.000+0000",
        "time": 1594553265000,
        "timeSecond": 1594553265
    }
```

But i want the `id` to be returned in this format :

```
"_id" : {"$oid":"5f0c5a19471f55820c201235"},
```

EDIT  :The class (and id field) is defined as follows :

```
public class Class1 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    public ObjectId id;
...
```

How to achieve this in Spring boot using the ObjectId type ,

Comment: Please post your Pojo class mapped to the MongoDB collection document. Also, see this post: [Spring Mongo Repository is unable to match String to ObjectId in _id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590544/spring-mongo-repository-is-unable-to-match-string-to-objectid-in-id-field/62592108#62592108).

Comment: thx see edit pls

Comment: What about your Pojo property definition for the field `"id": { "timestamp": ....}`?

Comment: ?? it is not that it's "$oid" : "str"

Comment: `{"$oid":"5f0c5a19471f55820c201235"}` is the [Extended JSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html) of `ObjectId`.

Comment: Have a _getter_ method, which returns as string value. Also, see the linked post in my earlier (first) comment.

Comment: ok also is it possible then to alter the name of the key "id" of the Id field to "_id" ? @Field("_id") is not working to change its name

Comment: The `_id` filed is _immutable_ (cannot change its value or rename or delete). Otherwise, you can _rename_ any other field's name in a document.

Comment: i am talking about the id of Java (not the _id of mongodb) how to change the name of the field id of java ?

Comment: with the getter you return a string not the Json format of the objectId

Comment: You can take a look at `Converter` interface in Spring, especially `MongoConverter` in Spring Data MongoDB.