# Spring data mongodb creates ObjectId on the saving and String _id on updating

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    private String id;
```

When I save an entity via spring repository it creates Id in DB:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("626ac45dbf00d30e6a67ac73")
```

When I select that entity, update a field and save it again, it creates a new item in the DB with Id:

```
"_id" : "626ac45dbf00d30e6a67ac73"
```

What should I do for keeping the same ids on the creation and updating entity?

Comment: You can type the id field as an ObjectId to begin with (`private ObjectId id`) or if you want it to be a string, set the value from the application code when building the initial object (something like `ObjectId.get().toString()`) instead of letting the database set it for you. Alternatively, since it sounds like you're using the `MongoOperations#save` function, you could use the `update` function instead.

Comment: remove ```@Field("_id")``` and check

Comment: You need to know the usage of the annotations `@Id`, `@Field` and `@MongoId` - how they affect the MongoDB document's `_id` field. See this post for some details: [Spring Mongo Repository is unable to match String to ObjectId in _id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590544/spring-mongo-repository-is-unable-to-match-string-to-objectid-in-id-field/62592108#62592108)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the properties below in your class:

```
@Id
@MongoId
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
@Column(name = "myId")
private String myId;
```

@MongoId - transforms the ID defined in your class as the primary ID of the document in MongoDB. This way, it does not generate the default ObjectId (MongoDB's default ID).

Comment: MongoId is a specialized Id annotation that may customize type conversion. By specifying it, you inhibit automatic type conversion to ObjectId by default as it implicitly specifies FieldType.IMPLICIT. There is no need to annotate Id alongside MongoId. Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/MongoId.html